# Request body not making it to middleware for joi validation

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, middleware

I have a middleware that validates my `user` object as users are created and also when they make edits. It worked not too long ago but I went to make a change this morning and realized it no longer works and I can't figure out why.

I've done some troubleshooting... the middleware function is being called (tested with a
`console.log`) but the `req.body` is coming through as `undefined` from the middleware function.

**Joi Schema**

```
const Joi = require('joi');

module.exports.userSchema = Joi.object({
    user: Joi.object({
        username: Joi.string().min(2).max(40).required(),
        password: Joi.string().min(8).max(15).required(),
        email: Joi.string().email({ minDomainSegments: 2, tlds: { allow: ['com', 'net'] } }).required(),
        location: Joi.string().alphanum(),
        image: Joi.string().alphanum(),
        website: Joi.string().uri({
            scheme: [
                /https?/
            ]
        }),
        stripeId: Joi.string().alphanum(),
    })
});
```

**Middleware function**

```
const { userSchema } = require('./schemas.js');
const ExpressError = require('./utils/ExpressError');

module.exports.validateUser = (req, res, next) => {
    const { error } = userSchema.validate(req.body);
    console.log("validation schema running");   <---- logs `validation schema running`
    console.log(req.body)  <--- `undefined`
    if (error) {
        const msg = error.details.map(el => el.message).join(',')
        throw new ExpressError(msg, 400)
    } else {
        next();
    }
}
```

**Router**

```
const { validateUser } = require('../middleware');

router.route('/:id')
    .get( isLoggedIn, isUser, catchAsync(users.showUser))
    .put( validateUser, isLoggedIn, upload.array('image'), catchAsync(users.updateUser))
```

And finally, the **Controller function**

```
module.exports.updateUser = async (req, res) => {
    const { id } = req.params;
    console.log("req body ", req.body);
    const user = await User.findByIdAndUpdate(id, { ...req.body.user });
    const imgs = req.files.map(f => ({ url: f.path, filename: f.filename }));
    user.image.push(...imgs);
    await user.save();
    res.redirect(`/users/${user._id}`);
};
```

`req.body` from controller function comes through as below while `req.body` from the middleware comes through as `undefined`.

```
req body  [Object: null prototype] {
  user: [Object: null prototype] {
    username: "Dan's Sands",
    location: '1 Main St, Austin, TX 78703',
    email: 'test@test.com',
    website: 'https://test.com'
  }
}
```

Why isn't the request body making it to my middleware function?

EDIT - I'm not sure if this would have any impact but adding the body parsing logic I have on my server:

**App.js**

```
app.use(bodyParser.raw({type: "application/json"}));
app.use(express.json({ limit: '1mb' }));
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
```

Comment: I wonder how your request makes it to the `updateUser` function if `req.body` is undefined during the validation ... Because I'd think the validator throws an error on an undefined body ...

Comment: And what happens if you revert the change you made today? Does ist start working again? If yes, what is your change?

Comment: Hi @derpirscher it's very odd -- the console first logs the `undefined` (since the request hits this function first) THEN logs the object second from the controller function `updateUser`. I added some of the body parsing code above I'm using and wondering if that has anything to do with it..???

Comment: The changes did not take place this morning rather I noticed the email domain I have on this test account should have been blocked by the Joi validation ( `@test.com`) but somehow had gotten through. The email validation used to work so this prompted me to look into the issue and uncover that none of the validation is working.

Comment: It looks like it is due to the parsing. If I change `app.use(bodyParser.raw({type: "application/json"}));` to `app.use(bodyParser.raw({type: "*/*"}));` req.body works. 

It's apparently due to my image since application/json doesn't allow multipart data (photo) so the whole body is blocked.

Comment: The body isn't "blocked". But if you only attach a bodyparser middleware for `application/json` of course it won't parse a `multipart/form-data` ...